# LinearLayout getBackground().getColor() return wrong int value

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am implementig UI Tests using espresso.
My boss wants me to check that after a certain action a linearLayout has a new and the correct color. I've wrote a custom matcher which looks like this

```
public static Matcher<View> withBgColor(final int color) {

    Checks.checkNotNull(color);

    return new BoundedMatcher<View, LinearLayout>(LinearLayout.class) {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(LinearLayout layout) {
            MyLog.debug(String.valueOf(color) + " vs " + String.valueOf(((ColorDrawable) layout.getBackground()).getColor()));
            return color == ((ColorDrawable) layout.getBackground()).getColor();
            //return color == (((PaintDrawable) layout.getBackground()).getPaint()).getColor();
        }
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("With background color: ");
        }
    };
}
```

My problem is that the comparison of the provided color and the color from the background are not the same. In the app I can see that the right color is set. It is done like this:

```
holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_300));
```

As soon as the test tries to compare the values they differ from each other:

```
Log: CustomMatcher: 17170432 vs -2039584
```

I call the matcher like this

```
.check(matches(withBgColor(R.color.grey_300)));
```

Can anyone help me how I can check if the color matches? The way I did fails everytime... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that both a *color* and a *color resource ID* are implemented as integers. You are passing the value of `R.color.grey_300`, which is a generated number representing the resource ID, instead of the color itself.

You should instead match in this way:
`.check(matches(withBgColor(context.getColor(R.color.grey_300))));`

If you are worried that `getColor()` is deprecated, use `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.grey_300)` instead.

Comment: Thanks that worked. What a stupid misstake.. Saved my day!

Comment: No problem! The exact same thing happened to me a while back when using `ArgbEvaluator` to animate some color values...